# Relations between distance function and gradient on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

An exercise on my textbook, is to show that on a Riemannian manifold $M$, the distance $d(x,y)$ is equal to $\sup \{f(x)-f(y):f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, with $\|\nabla f\| \leq 1\}$.

Using $\langle\nabla f,X\rangle=X(f)$, it's easy to show that the left hand side is **larger** than the right one (i.e. $d(x,y) \geq sup\{...\}$). But I cannot found a simple solution to fix the other side.

I thought it could be done by approximationg $f(y)=d(x,y)$, which is a Lip-$1$ function, by a family of smooth function, but it may be too hard for a undergraduate textbook exercise. Or maybe we should consider find a $f$, whose gradient along a curve is just the curve's tangent vector field?

Could you please give me some hint? Great thx!

Comment: What is your definition of $d(x,y)$?

Comment: @Uskebasi $d(x,y)=inf\{\int_{0}^{t} \| \gamma '(a)\|da, where\  \gamma \ is\  a\  smooth\ curve\ with\ \gamma(0)=x, \gamma(t)=y\}$

Comment: What kinds of techniques are you supposed to use (I have no idea what an undergraduate RG course would look like...).

Comment: @JohnMa I have learned do Carmo's _Riemannian Geometry_, and I am now reading comparison therorem and some charateristric class of pricipal-G bundle. I hope that techniques like Lipschitz function and smooth approximation, which may be in geometry measure theory(?), could be avoid. What I want to avoid is this→http://www.mat.ucm.es/~dazagrar/articulos/AFLRjmaa.pdf

Answer (score 5):

As you said you were able to prove the first inequality, I will only prove the second one, i.e.
\begin{equation}\sup \{ |f(x)-f(y)| : f \in C^{\infty}(M), || \nabla f|| \leq 1\}\leq d(x,y).
\end{equation}
As the distance function is defined as an infimum we will prove this by approximation. In these situations it‘s often easier to prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ the weaker inequality 
\begin{equation}\sup \{ |f(x)-f(y)| : f \in C^{\infty}(M), || \nabla f|| \leq 1\}\leq d(x,y)+\epsilon
\end{equation}holds.

So let $\epsilon>0.$ By definition there exists a smooth curve $c:[0,1]\to M$ connecting $x$ and $y,$ such that $l(c)\leq d(x,y)+\epsilon.$ Then for every $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ whose gradient is bounded by 1, we get by the CS inequality 
\begin{align*}|f(y)-f(x)|&=|f(c(1))-f(c(0))|\\&=\bigg|\int_0^1 (f\circ c)'(t) dt \bigg| \\&=\bigg| \int_0^1 \langle \nabla f (c(t)), c'(t)\rangle dt \bigg| \leq \int_0^1 |\langle \nabla f (c(t)), c'(t)\rangle| dt \\&\leq \int_0^1 \|\nabla f(c(t))\| \|c'(t)\|dt\\&\leq \int_0^1 \|c'(t)\| dt=l(c)\leq d(x,y)+\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Taking the supremum over all such $f$ we obtain the desired (weaker) inequality.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry that I actually didn't figure out the opposite inequality......I edited the question just now, really sorry about my mistake....

Comment: I have a solution. I‘ll post it as soon as I have time.

Comment: Do you know that for every $p \in M$ and every $L>1$ there exists a nbhd $U$ of $p$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi:U\to \varphi(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{1}{L}d(x,y)\leq ||\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)||\leq L d(x,y)$ holds for all $x,y \in U$?

Comment: Sorry I didn't figure it out, I thought it could be done considerting the exponential map with nbd U small enough, but failed to prove it formally. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some hint, maybe, included in your new solution?

Comment: Could you ask this in another question? Because otherwise the answer would become very long.

Comment: Fine, I've post it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744280/relations-between-distance-function-and-gradient-on-a-riemannian-manifold-ii