# Bound on variation from partition of unity on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In the answer by Jackel Frieder
to this question, [Relations between distance function and gradient on a Riemannian manifold (II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744280/relations-between-distance-function-and-gradient-on-a-riemannian-manifold-ii) on the distance formula for Riemannian manifolds in terms of sup, we cover the manifold by open (convex) subsets $U_\alpha$ where we have local defined smooth functions $F_\alpha$ whose variation is bound by the distance (with Lipschitz constant no greater than 1) : $|F_\alpha(x)-F_\alpha(y)|\leq d(x,y)$

Using a partition of unity $(\Psi_\alpha)$ subordinated to the cover, it is claimed that the glued function, $F=\sum \Psi_\alpha F_\alpha$  locally is also bound by the distance.

I can easily see why it's locally bound by a multiple of the distance function (it's no surprise, since it's locally Lipschitz), but I don't get the bound (roughly, something like the Lipschitz constant being $\leq 1$).

I did try with an open neighborhood where almost all the $\Psi_\alpha$ are $0$ (locally finiteness) and things like making appear the variation of an $F_\alpha$, but I don't get the right bound (namely, $1$).
Thank you for any help